# What is Merge Module's version used for?

Tags: wix, windows-installer

I don't find anywhere that the version attribute of a merge module is used, not even for upgrading scenarios. What is it used for then?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's only used during the merge process to validate that the version of the module is compatible with the version the installer is expecting to consume.